# How to create a stored procedure within another stored procedure in SQL Server 2008

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008

I want to create a stored procedure to be used within a stored procedure something like shown below. Is this possible?

```
CREATE procedure parentSP
as 

--child SP definition.
CREATE procedure childSP1 @inputArg varchar(50)
as 
--do something.
Go

--call child sp within parentSP
execute childSP1 '10'

Go
```

Comment: This seems liks an odd requirement - what's your motivation for doing this?

Comment: In answer to your question Will A though it's quite a few years later I have the same need to create a stored procedure within a stored procedure and the reasoning is I track my tempdb usage using a custom stored proc that uses the fileproperty keyword which can only be used within the current database context. I'll be creating a sub stored proc inside tempdb so that I can get accurate results and then checking after that if the stored proc exists. Since tempdb gets re-created every time I'll need to keep the stored proc creation code but won't worry about re-creating it every time.

Comment: A reason for wanting to do this would be: if you want to create a proc, function, type, etc. temporarily only for this procedure, and want to delete them all before the procedure completes.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You can use exec:

```
CREATE procedure parentSP
as 
exec('CREATE procedure childSP1 @inputArg varchar(50)
as 
--do something.')

--call child sp within parentSP
execute childSP1 '10'
Go
```

Comment: Of course, this will error the second time it's run, unless you drop the procedure later also (or only run the inner create if the proc doesn't exist)

Comment: if you create a store proc on the fly, you should drop once done using it.