# is it possible to create a stored proc from a stored proc?

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server, stored-procedures

Using sql server 2014.  Was asked to create all my stored procedures and see if it is possible to do that from a stored procedure?

Comment: Yes, call a SQL statement starting with `create procedure`.

Comment: Similar to:http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6450270/how-to-create-a-stored-procedure-within-another-stored-procedure-in-sql-server-2

Comment: thank you that was helpful.

Answer (score 0):

Sure, do it like this:

```
create procedure creatorproc
as 
begin
    declare @sql as nvarchar(max);
    set @sql = 'create procedure newproc as begin select ''hello''; end; ' 
    exec(@sql);
end;

go

exec creatorproc ;
```